# Soft delete nested entities in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have some nested entities, and I want to Auto soft-delete children of a record when I soft-delete that record(like hard-delete). How can I do this? And what is the best approach?

```
class Base
{
    bool isDeleted { set; get; }
}

class A : Base
{
    //Collection of B
}

class B : Base
{
    //Collection of C
}

class C : Base
{
    //Collection of D
}
....
```

For example:

Table A:

```
    Id    ForeignKey(B Id)    isDeleted 
    -------------------------------------
    1        1                 false
```

Table B:

```
   Id    ForeignKey(C Id)    isDeleted
   -------------------------------------
    1        1                 false
    1        2                 false
    1        3                 false
```

Table C:

```
    Id    ForeignKey(D Id)    isDeleted
    -------------------------------------
    1        1                 false
    1        2                 false
    2        3                 false
    2        4                 false
    3        5                 false
    3        6                 false
```

Code:

```
public void SoftDeleteA()
{
     //A.isDeleted = true;
     //???How to soft-delete related records in B,C,D ,...
     //SaveChanges();
}
```

Now when I soft-delete rows from A, all the rows of B and C must also be soft-deleted

Comment: how and where do you delete the primary record?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: @Dave I Update my question

Comment: @Amir133 sorry, i don't understand. when you say How to SoftDelete Relational Record in B,C,D ,... how are they related to A? Is there any navigation properties? If your relationships are configured properly, there should be a navigation property in class A. if so, you can simply loop through the collection (if 1 to many relation) or access a single entity (1 to 1 relation) and mark isDeleted as true.

Comment: @Dave Ok, Thanks. there is a relation between A and B ,B and C, C and D ,.... . Please watch again I add an example. I want the best and the efficience way and less code to delete all related records.

Comment: when use hard delete, all related records deleted automatically, so I want a way to Soft delete all related records automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way to achieve this with entity framework. Soft-delete is just a term and it doesn't actually delete the record, but only updates a single column value, so no related entities are affected with this. However, you can do this with either entity framework or SQL trigger. Since you want this to happen automatically, create an update trigger on table A and set isDeleted in related tables from updated record.

Articles related to trigger: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

https://www.tutorialgateway.org/after-update-triggers-in-sql-server/

https://www.sqlshack.com/triggers-in-sql-server/

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Insert-Update-and-Delete-Triggers-in-SQL-Server-with-example.aspx

With entity framework, you need fetch your parent along with all children first, modify them individually and save to database.

**Example:**

```
public A FetchA()
{
  return _context.A
          .Include(a=>a.CollectionB)
          .ThenInclude(b=>b.CollectionC)
          .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}

public void SoftDeleteA()
{
    var a = FetchA();
    if(a !=null)
    {
       a.isDeleted = true;

       // loop through all related records and update them
       if(a.CollectionB?.Any()== true)
       { 
           foreach(var itemB in a.CollectionB)
           {
               itemB.isDeleted = true;

               // loop through all related records and update them
               if(itemB.CollectionC?.Any()== true)
               { 
                   foreach(var itemC in itemB.CollectionC)
                   {
                       itemC.isDeleted = true;
                   }         
               }
           }
       }

       // save changes at last
       _context.Update(a);
       await _context.SaveChangesAsync() ;
    }

}
```

OR if you have option to use SQL, just run the raw sql which is way faster than doing with EF.

**Example:**

```
update b
set isDeleted = a.isDeleted
from B b
inner join A a on b.ID = a.ID
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave for the reply. But now I have another question (I know I have to create a new question for another question, but I want to know if there is an answer or not), is there an automatic way to do the opposite of this operation, that is, I delete a record from Table D and records Related to be removed in the parent tables(A,B,C)

Comment: @Amir133 i don't know the logic off hand, but if you could write a logic to perform this, you can place it at the same place as the answer. may be its better to open a new question for this.

Comment: @Amir133 probably it is not best to do so, as the parent may have multiple children, so deleting one child should not delete the parent. or else you will also have to consider deleting all child of the parent using the logic in answer. but you could try fetching the parent from child and just use the logic from answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like [Recursive Functions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/955025/C-Sharp-interview-questions-part4what-is-a-recursive-function-in/);

```
class Base
{
      public virtual bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
      public virtual void DeleteMethod(int modifiedBy)
      {
          IsDeleted = true;
          ModifiedMethod(modifiedBy);
      }
}

class A : Base
{
    //Collection of B
    
    public override void DeleteMethod(int modifiedBy)
    {
        B.ForEach(oe => oe.DeleteMethod(modifiedBy));
        base.DeleteMethod(modifiedBy);
    }
}

class B : Base
{
    //Collection of C
    
    public override void DeleteMethod(int modifiedBy)
    {
        C.ForEach(oe => oe.DeleteMethod(modifiedBy));
        base.DeleteMethod(modifiedBy);
    }
}

class C : Base
{
    //Collection of D
    
    public override void DeleteMethod(int modifiedBy)
    {
        D.ForEach(oe => oe.DeleteMethod(modifiedBy));
        base.DeleteMethod(modifiedBy);
    }
}
```

when called some **{ParentClass}.DeleteMethod()**, its start operations to child classes. its same thing above answer but covering all inherited classes, not need write loop again every methods.

```
public async Task SoftDeleteAsync()
{
    ..
    A.DeleteMethod(userid);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```